# Numpy: How to query multiple multidimensional arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Assume I have 3 arrays:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],
            [3,4,5],
            [6,7,8]])

b=np.array([[1],
            [5],
            [4]])

c=np.array([[1],
            [2],
            [3]])
```

Now, I want to select all rows from a, which have a matching row with b=4 and c=3.

**So the question is, how to do:**

```
d = np.subset(a,'b==4 and c==3')
```

In this case I expect as output

```
[6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
>>> a=np.array([[1,2,3],
...             [3,4,5],
...             [6,7,8]])
>>> 
>>> b=np.array([[1],
...             [5],
...             [4]])
>>> 
>>> c=np.array([[1],
...             [2],
...             [3]])
>>>
>>> a[((b==4) & (c==3)).squeeze()]
array([[6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: The equivalent using `np.where`: `a[np.where((b==4) & (c==3))[0]]` (not needed, probably even worse performance, but just for adding another option).